# Is there any way to prune intermediate git commits?

Tags: git, administration

Hope this is the right forum for this question... tell me if not.

I'm a basic user of git, but I've been developing this app for the past few months, using the principle "commit frequently".  So now I just ran `git rev-list --all --count`, and I find I have 425 commits.

This may be crazy ... or it may be perfectly normal.  I have no idea.

The thing is the repository is getting to be a bit unwieldy and what I'd like to do in an ideal world is just go through the commits, eliminating 2 out of every 3: I'd want the messages of the commits which are to be deleted to be somehow added to the messages of those which are to remain...

There is a "manual" way of doing this: I plod through the entire repo, checking out every 3rd commit, carefully noting the text from the commits I'm not saving, and adding them systematically to the "every third one"'s message.

At the same time, obviously, I'm creating a new repo, which is using only those "every 3rd commits".  I haven't tried this yet, partly because it strikes me as a bit of a bore which will take an awful lot of time: is there anything in git, or any tool anyone's invented, which can help with this sort of task?

Comment: What makes a ~400-commit repositoriy "a bit unwieldy"?

Comment: Thanks.  At least it didn't make you laugh: first hurdle cleared.  Well I'm occasionally backing up this repo to Google Drive: at the moment it is 11 MB, not too hairy.  But the basic thought in my mind is: having cleared those individual steps one by one some time ago I don't need to keep all 425 tiny-step commits from months ago... it's really a question of the principle of the thing rather than (as yet) a practical matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why

Git history works best when it actually tells the story of the development process. When you end up needing to dig through the history (e.g. to search when a bug was introduced, when it was fixed, etc.), it does not help to see commits titled ["Add today's changes"](http://whatthecommit.com/); they tell you how the code was changed but not why.

Rewriting the commit history *is* commonly done (to merge commits, swap them around, and so on) – but if you just arbitrarily delete 2 out of every 3 commits, it will likely remain *just as useless* as before. Instead, rewrite history to clean up things like "whoops, fix a typo", or to add more detail to commit messages.

Of course, the above is a matter of opinion, but it's generally more practical to let the computer remember things so that you don't have to.

425 commits is normal for a several-month project. It's also relatively tiny compared to many real-world Git repositories (which measure commits by the thousand). If your concern is disk space usage, and Git hasn't run the periodic `git gc` yet, try running it manually and see if that helps.

For backups over the network, `git push` will be far more efficient than manually uploading whole repositories, as it knows exactly what needs to be uploaded and what is already there.

#### Getting back to the point

Git has many tools for rewriting history – the most common is `git rebase --interactive`, which can do exactly the type of edits that you want.

```
; on a feature branch, to rewrite everything that's not yet in master
git rebase -i master

; on master, to go through the *entire history*
git rebase -i --root
```

Running it in interactive mode opens a "todo list" in a text editor, with one line per commit and an "action" in front of it.

- Moving the lines around will reorder the commits. (However, changing the text *will not* update commit messages – they're just previews. Use `reword` to edit the real message.)
- Changing the action from `pick` to `squash` will combine the commit with the one above – resulting in a single commit that has both messages as well.
- The `fixup` action is similar, but only keeps the 1st message.

That's the basics, because plenty of tutorials have already been written in far more detail. For example, the *Git Book* has [a chapter on history rewriting](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

Comment: Thanks... this is very informative for my low level and I shall examine closely what you say.  Can you "push" to a repo actually resident on Google Drive, I wonder, or do you have to set something up on GitHub, for example?  I actually have an as yet unread ebook on GitHub, since for someone like me (not an IT professional) it's quite tricky to understand how it works.

Comment: Google Drive -- not by default, no. (Although there's a plugin for pushing to Dropbox.) In general, you can either push to a personal server where you have SSH access, or sign up for a Git hosting account somewhere. (GitHub is popular for public projects, whereas BitBucket and GitLab are two alternatives which also offer private repositories for free.)

Comment: Thanks again.  I shall look up BitBucket and/or GitLab asap!

Comment: Note that both websites provide free hosting accounts _and_ offer installable "enterprise" products, so don't get confused by the front page advertisements; just go straight to the "sign up" link. Also, even if you don't use GitHub, its help area has many tutorials for `git push` and SSH which apply to all sites equally.